Svelte:window component onload not triggering
In Svelte5, why is the onload event not triggering the function foo() in src/routers/+layout.svelte?
<script>
    const foo = () => console.log('foo triggered')
</script>

<svelte:window onload={foo} />


I'm guessing here, but most likely the load event on the document has already fired before your own JS code runs that adds the listener for that event. In a +layout.svelte, you should use onMount() instead.

That makes sense. onMount() is a bit too Svelte4-ish to me. I got it to work both with $effect(() => console.log(“foo triggered”)) and <svelte:window use:foo />, both in Svelte5 style. onMount() is not deprecated, so it’s a viable solution (still), too.
